# My app keeps getting rejected on Google Playstore because of privacy policy

Tags: android, google-apps

My app was rejected by Google even though we were just uploading an update, the app already existed on Google Play store before. The main reason that the app was getting rejected was because of the privacy policy. We went through with it with a fine comb and amended all that we needed to. However, since the last time we uploaded the app there has been no response from Google. And the existing app was removed from Google Play Store and the same app is working perfectly on the App store.

Now I want to understand, how the appeal section works. Other than providing the proof i.e signed documents and all that is needed, is there another hurdle that we would have to cross?

The main reason that the app was getting rejected was because of the privacy policy. We went through with it with a fine comb and amended all that we needed to. However, since the last time we uploaded the app there has been no response from Google. And the existing app was removed from Google Play Store and the same app is working perfectly on the App store.

We were expecting this update to go through as smoothly as the update for ios.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons to reject an app because of the **Privacy policy**. Here I will show our case.

To check the particular reason, you can go to

[Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/console) **=>** YOUR_APP **=>** Policy status **=>** Policy issues.

- Clicking on the policy issue, You can see the **Issue details** page like below.

[image]

- Please click on the **View email** button. You can see the full details with the reason on the page below:

[image]

- Here in our case the issue was we need to mention that we are collecting and using the **Phone number** on the privacy policy page.

---

Note: Also make sure you provide the correct information in

[Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/console) **=>** YOUR_APP **=>** App content **=>** Data safety.

Please provide each piece of information carefully and correctly.

Comment: Thanks for this Rumit! Much appreciated. 

Our app was rejected again however, we haven't received any email we usually do get it but this time there isn't any email. 

Is there a way you can receive more information about why the app was rejected by looking at it from the UI? 

Note: I have looked through all options and I am hoping its something that you can help me find.

Comment: @Opsidei, there must be **View email** button in **Issue details** page. Please check the first image in answer.